# Multiple classes in a single file leads to overload warnings

Tags: google-closure-compiler, es6-class

I've recently started playing around with the closure compiler and ES6, and I've noticed something that I think is a bit strange.  When I compile the following code:

```
export class Test
{
    constructor(arg)
    {
        this.arg = arg;
    }
}

class Test2
{
    constructor(diffArg)
    {
        this.diffArg = diffArg;
    }
}
```

I get this output when I compile with ADVANCED:

```
java -jar closure-compiler-v20170910.jar --compilation_level ADVANCED --language_in ECMASCRIPT6_TYPED --language_out ECMASCRIPT5 --js_output_file ui.js --js javascript/*.js --externs javascript/externs/externs.js --jscomp_off missingProperties

Test.js:11: WARNING - Function and method overloads are not supported and type information might be lost
        constructor(diffArg)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Test.js:5: ERROR - variable arg is undeclared
                this.arg = arg;
                           ^^^
```

It looks like the compiler is complaining because there are two functions with the same name in the file - even though they are in different classes - and the error comes in because the second function replaces the first.  If I compile with SIMPLE, I get the warning but not the error, and the emitted code seems to contain the second constructor definition.  To get the code to compile properly, I need to put each class into its own file.

My question is whether this is expected behavior or not - I don't believe that there is anything in the ES6 spec about only having one class per file, and since each function is in a different class, I would have expected that I can use the same name for each of them (especially for the constructor).  Is there a way to get around this, or is having each class in its own file the right way to go?

Comment: This is certainly not an ES6 issue as you can have as many class definitions as you want in a file.  I wonder if you're running a version of the closure compiler that doesn't support all of ES6.

Comment: I'm not able to recreate this issue in Closure-compiler.